# How to add SSO to an azure bot on microsoft teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Followed steps documented to enable bot sso

1. Created a bot.
2. Added Microsoft Teams under Channels.
3. Under Configuration added the messaging endpoint. e.g. (https://myproxy.proxyapp.com/teams/app/activity).
4. Generated a client secret for the Microsoft app id.
5. Added "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect" as the Redirect URI for Web platform under Authentication for my Microsoft App.
6. Under API Permissions for my Microsoft App added "email offline_access openid profile". "User.Read" was available by default.
7. Under Expose an API added "api://botid-{Microsoft app id}". Added scope "access_as_user". Added web (1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264) and desktop (5e3ce6c0-2b1f-4285-8d4b-75ee78787346) client applications.
8. In the Manifest file for my Microsoft app updated "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2.
9. For my bot added an OAuth Connection as below

[image]

10. Created an app on Microsoft Teams and associated my Micorsoft App Id as the bot id. Attached is the manifest for my Microsoft Teams app.

When I install this app to Microsoft Teams the bot is shown in the chat tab which is expected. Further the document says as a 1st step
"The bot sends a message with an OAuthCard that contains the tokenExchangeResource property.". How can I achieve this?

When I type "Hi" for the very 1st time on the bot I receive the below JSON at my messaging endpoint

```
{
  "text": "hi",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "text/html",
      "content": "<div>hi</div>"
    }
  ],
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2021-10-05T18:27:21.5454867Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2021-10-05T23:57:21.5454867+05:30",
  "id": "1633458441515",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
  "from": {
    "id": "29:1kR5UGDG5iTFhsVadKAadeYuzsLEhMYK_YFxb7_Y62nAilJVLIMiPtC8oLrGGyK7wZTaFc8-jlVxJq3q0bpoBMw",
    "name": "Ashish Sood",
    "aadObjectId": "3836************************be046"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "tenantId": "1734*************************bb8ecf",
    "id": "a:1xMOdsbv02hfl2J4GUGA7-WemaLGCOxFlzsSNcQ9StjIMAAKn64tJ0zxKk25b02NMTl3rc7nbNffMZGXVYfraNIDKnptC01oeLRv7Ngh2WMCyOrmBT2KaDleQXSU2s4MY"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "28:18c9**********************02b9",
    "name": "NOW_Virtual_Agent_SSO_Bot"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "en-GB",
      "country": "GB",
      "platform": "Mac",
      "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "1734************************b8ecf"
    }
  },
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "localTimezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
}
```

How do I use this JSON to complete the 6 steps mentioned at
[add sso authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-your-teams-application-manifest-for-your-bot)

Microsoft Teams App manifest.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "9a83***************************177d",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.devapp",
  "developer": {
    "name": "SSO Bot App",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.teams.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.teams.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.teams.com/termsofuse"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "SSO Bot App",
    "full": "SSO Bot App"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "SSO Bot App",
    "full": "SSO Bot App"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "conversations",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    },
    {
      "entityId": "about",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "18c9**********************02b9",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "token.botframework.com"
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "18c9**********************02b9",
    "resource": "api://botid-18c9**********************02b9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please check on this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ceml
Also please let us know if you still need any help.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Thanks for the reply. Below is my issue

1. All the demos and sample codes are either in C# or Javascript (Node.js) or DotNetCore and are using the Bot Builder frame SDK.

2. We have an already running bot to which we need to add SSO capability. All demos and sample code either create a bot and the app using Visual Studio or Yeoman generator and then add Bot Builder as a dependency using npm. That's not my case.

3. I created the bot on Azure portal under Bot Services->AzureBot. Configured the AAD app backing the bot under App Registrations.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Finally created the MS Teams app using the App Studio feature within MS Teams and attached my bot to this MS Teams app from there.

4. Further in my scenario I have my activity endpoint i.e. /api/messages defined in a proxy server which is programmed in LUA programming language. The demos use ngrok which is always pointing to there local server.

5. Is there a way where instead of depending upon the bot builder SDK I have an API way of completing the SSO flow for my bot. For e.g. currently I use below 3 API to complete my OAuth flow

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

6. What I am looking for is a way that when my activity endpoint receives a 'Hi' or 'Hello' message for the very 1st time can I create a JSON which contains the OAuth Card with 'tokenExchangeResource' property defined

Comment: Could you please reverify your exchange URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-your-teams-application-manifest-for-your-bot

Comment: Also you need to explicitly send a OAuth card. Please check on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-your-teams-application-manifest-for-your-bot

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft My exchange URL is correct. As per the format in the docs. Exactly. How to send an OAuth card as a JSON format. All examples are for C# or .NET or Node.js. Also there's no mention in the docs for how to populate the TokenExchangeResource. In docs it says "For the Teams channel, only the Id property, which uniquely identifies a token request, is honored." How to fetch or generate this Id value for the TokenExchangeResource?

Comment: TokenExchangeResource URL contains bot id. Refer this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-the-azure-portal-with-the-oauth-connection
Refer below docs & sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue and spit through the nodejs/.net bot framework code to find what JSON is exactly sent for an OAuth card. We ended up with the follow JSON:

```json
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "content": {
                "connectionName": "<name of your sso oauth connection>",
                "text": "<some text, is not shown>",
                "tokenExchangeResource": {
                    "id": "<some random id, for validation in invoke request>"
                }
            },
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth"
        }
    ],
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "conversation": {
        "id": "<conversation ID>"
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "<your conversation bot id>"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "<conversation user id>"
    },
    "serviceUrl": "<service URL of conversation>",
    "type": "message"
}
```